# How to create linear parallel magnetic field lines

Tags: magnetic-fields, nanoscience

I am trying to make ferrofluids create a flat surface between two points. Most of the magnet configurations I have seen have field lines that arc.

So I'm asking if there are any circumstances where there exists several field lines that are linear and parralel to each other?

Comment: Inside a (long) coil? Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_coil

Comment: there are an infinite number of "field lines". These are connected through the divergence [see here](http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter2/2.7.html)

Comment: The Helmholtz coil looks promising. I'm trying to use magnets to flaten the surface of viscous oils quicker after they are disturbed. But at the moment when I hold magnes near a ferrofluid I am getting spikes directed along the field lines. I figured if I can make the field lines linear and uniform I could get a nice flat surface.

Comment: That may not work unless you have some way to damp the energy of the waves. A magnetic field won't stop a surface wobbling unless the energy of motion is dissipated somehow. An electrically conductive fluid might work better in a mag field.

Comment: When you say damp the energy of the waves, what do you mean? I thought the magnetic material would simply remain fixed along the field lines?